# Issue while updating gradle version of an old application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to update an old project to androidx .
Gradle version of the project is - 4.2.2

I tried to update the gradle version to 7.4.1,but getting this error

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tbruyelle/rxpermissions2/rxpermissions/0.9.1/rxpermissions-0.9.1.pom
> - https://maven.google.com/com/tbruyelle/rxpermissions2/rxpermissions/0.9.1/rxpermissions-0.9.1.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/tbruyelle/rxpermissions2/rxpermissions/0.9.1/rxpermissions-0.9.1.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/tbruyelle/rxpermissions2/rxpermissions/0.9.1/rxpermissions-0.9.1.pom
> - file:/applicationpath/app/libs/rxpermissions-0.9.1.aar
> - file:/applicationpath/app/libs/rxpermissions.aar
> - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/tbruyelle/rxpermissions2/rxpermissions/0.9.1/rxpermissions-0.9.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:2.0.0

how to fix this issue?

I tried to update the gradle version of the project

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is related to a missing dependency com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions, I think you need to reconfigure the dependencyResolution repositories; if you check the [documentation](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) of that library, the current version is `0.12`, and they've included it in the jitpack repo, consider adding the following to your build script:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```